# OSX - Composer - lib-openssl requirements

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, php-openssl

Since the last XCode Update to version 7.3.1 i run into problems with **composer** and **openssl** on OSX. It worked before update.

I try to update packages via composer update. The package **"ricardoper/twitteroauth"** requires **lib-openssl: "*"**.

The following error is thrown while running composer update:

```
ricardoper/twitteroauth v2.1.5 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
```

**PHP Version Infos:**

```
php -v
PHP 5.5.34 (cli) (built: Apr 22 2016 19:16:58) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

php -i | grep OpenSSL
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => LibreSSL 2.2.6
OpenSSL Header Version => LibreSSL 2.2.6
OpenSSL support => enabled
```

What could have happened?

Comment: Have you tried opening Xcode and make sure you don't have to accept any agreements? Most of the time it failed on my machine, was because of the service agreements. If that's the case, just open xcode, accept the agreements and run composer again.

Comment: I run into it too, but unfortunately it did not help in this case. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: Have you tried removing all packages and run composer again? Maybe reinstalling composer?

Comment: What does `composer show --platform` tell you?

Comment: I did not know the show platform command. In the listing the lib-openssl is missing. I will try to reinstall composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having the same problem, and I upgraded to PHP 5.6, and the error went away. Not sure if that's an option for you, but that's the only thing that fixed this for me...

Comment: Thanks for your help! I upgraded to php 5.6 on OSX and now composer update works again.

I used this tutorial to update from php 5.5. to 5.6:
[How to upgrade to PHP 7 or version 5.6 on Mac OSX 10.11 El Capitan and OSX 10.6 - OSX 10.10](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/)