# Lib-OpenSSL Dependency issue Laravel and Composer on OSX

Tags: macos, laravel, openssl, composer-php, jwt

## My Issue

In short, when I run `composer update`, I am getting the following error:

```
  Problem 1
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.4 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.5 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.6 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.7 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.8 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.9 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.1 requires namshi/jose 2.2.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.2 requires namshi/jose 2.2.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.3 requires namshi/jose 2.2.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.0 requires namshi/jose 2.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3].
    - namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 5.0.1 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 5.0.0 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.2.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.2.1 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.2.0 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.3 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.1 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.0 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - Installation request for tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.* -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 0.5.5, 0.5.6, 0.5.7, 0.5.8, 0.5.9].
```

## Additional Information

I am very unsure of the cause of this issue as I cannot be certain when it arose. All I know is that it has been working over the passed few days, maybe even earlier today...

There are a few things that I have done today that may have caused this:

- I installed and configured supervisord
- I installed and configured beanstalkd
- I installed the latest Mac OSX updates (more info here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT206230)

***All of the above may have absolutely nothing to do with this, it may be purely coincidental***

## What I have Tried

I have lost track of the number of things I have tried, but here are a few:

- Changing the version of `"tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"` to the latest alpha release (this worked, but I then had issues with the implementation of JWT-Auth) so I had to revert
- I have spent ages playing around with the versions of each of the dependencies and whilst these do, inevitably change the error message, they still do not fix the issue
- I upgraded to the latest version of openssl using `brew upgrade openssl`. However, this did not update openssl in PHP as I am using MAMP (I think), and I do not have control over which version of openssl PHP is compiled with...

## My Research

I have spent hours searching various sites, trying various things and exploring many many many potential solutions but nothing has, yet, solved this issue for me. These are a few of sites/pages I found:

- [laravel composer install could not solve installable package for tymon/jwt-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322446/laravel-composer-install-could-not-solve-installable-package-for-tymon-jwt-auth)
- [OSX - Composer - lib-openssl requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520011/osx-composer-lib-openssl-requirements)
- [the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473456/the-requested-linked-library-openssl-has-the-wrong-version-installed)
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/the-requested-linked-library-openssl-has-the-wrong-version-installed
- http://www.litphp.info/the_requested_linked_library_openssl_has_the_wrong_version_installed

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same problem on Mac and MAMP, I tracked it down to it checking my apple PHP version instead of my MAMP version.  I resolved this by creating a symlink from /usr/local/bin to my MAMP PHP.

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin/php php
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you -- required that I upgrade MAMP PRO 3.5 -> 4.0.5 first

Comment: Hi @Dayveian now my php artisan gives nothing any help?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a matter of not having php mcrypt, which mean php wasn't compiled with openssl support. Installing php70-mcrypt solved it for me. Beware that it will recompile php.

`brew install php70-mcrypt`

My current versions are:

- Homebrew 1.1.1
- Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 81b69; last commit 2016-11-20)
- PHP 7.0.13 (cli) (built: Nov 21 2016 11:26:59) ( NTS )
- OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MAMP, so needed to tell my Mac to use the MAMP version of PHP.

In terminal, run:

`nano ~/.bash_profile
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.27/bin:$PATH`

Then quit terminal and try running `composer install` again

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Mamp Pro (Version 4.1 at the time of this answer), there is an option to make the Mamp Pro version of PHP available on the command line, which is the easiest solution in my opinion.

First, open the MAMP Pro main window and select PHP from the left-side menu:

[image: Select PHP from the menu]

Then right underneath where you select which version of PHP to run, there is a checkbox to "Make this version available on the command line".

[image: Checkbox to make this version available on the command line]

Then just save the changes and restart your terminal. If you type `php -v`, you should see the updated version of PHP.